# $px^2+6y^2 \equiv1 \bmod 3p$ where $p\equiv5 \bmod8$

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is a prime with $p\equiv5 \bmod8$, prove that $px^2+6y^2 \equiv1 \bmod 3p$ has no solutions for any integers $x,y$.

I can rewrite it as $px^2+6y^2\equiv 16(24)$ but have no idea how to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x,y$ exist.

The modular equation implies:
$$px^2 \equiv 1 \;\;\text{(mod 3)} \qquad (1)$$
$$6y^2\equiv 1 \;\;\text{(mod $p$)} \qquad (2)$$

---

**In $\bf(1)$**

$x^2 \equiv 0 \text{  or  } 1 \;\;\text{(mod 3)}$ for any $x$, so here $x^2 \equiv 1 \;\;\text{(mod 3)}$ and $p \equiv 1 \;\;\text{(mod 3)}$.

Together with $p \equiv 5 \;\text{(mod 8)}$, this gives:

$$p \equiv 13 \;\;\text{(mod 24)}\qquad (3)$$

---

**In $\bf{(2)}$**

From $(3)$, $\; -\frac{p-1}{6}$ is an integer.

Multiplying this to both sides yields:

$$y^2 \equiv -\frac{p-1}{6} \;\;\text{(mod $p$)}$$

Let's use the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Using the properties of the Legendre symbol,
$$1=\bigg(\frac{1}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{1-p}{p}\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{6}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{-\frac{p-1}{6}}{p}\bigg)$$

By $(3)$, we know $\big(\frac{6}{p}\big)=\big(\frac{2}{p}\big)\big(\frac{3}{p}\big)=(-1) \times 1 = -1$.

$$\therefore\bigg(\frac{-\frac{p-1}{6}}{p}\bigg)=-1 \quad\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$

Hence the proof that no solution exists.